# Regular Expression usage with ls

Tags: regex, ls, glob

I am trying to use ER *(Extended Regular Expressions)* with `ls` like `ls .+\..+`.

I am trying to print all files which contains an extension 
(I know I could have used `ls *.*`, but I wanted to try using ER).

When I run that code I get this error: `ls: .+..+: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I think you're confusing REs and shell wildcards. The answer will also depend on what she'll you're using.

Comment: So I can't use RE in ls?

Comment: Unless you're using some fancy, non-standard script for ls, ls doesn't take regex.  Also, the os will process special wildcard chars like * before it gets passed to your command.  Try using 'find' instead

Comment: `echo $SHELL
/bin/bash`

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You are confusing regular expression with [shell globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html). If you want to use regular expression to match file names you could do:

```
$ ls | egrep '.+\..+'
```

Comment: Got it. So, first of all I have to check if what I am trying to use accepts RE.

Comment: If the pattern can't be matched with `globbing` alone then you will have to use an alternative method. *F.Y.I* the tool `find` supports regexp matching.

Comment: `ls -f` would be probably faster if the list of files is very long.

Comment: `shellcheck` shows "Use find instead of ls to better handle non-alphanumeric filenames.
See [SC2012](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2012)." for `ls` and "egrep is non-standard and deprecated. Use grep -E instead.
See [SC2196](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2196)." for `egrep`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't say what shell you are using, but they generally don't support regular expressions that way, although there are common *nix CLI tools (`grep`, `sed`, etc) that do.

What shells like bash do support is *[globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)*, which uses some similiar characters (eg, *) but is not the same thing.

Newer versions of bash do have a regular expression operator, `=~`:

```
for x in `ls`; do 
    if [[ $x =~ .+\..* ]]; then 
        echo $x; 
    fi; 
done
```

Comment: Cool! I have never heard about it! :) So it is only use `=~` and the interpreter will understand that what I am trying to match is a RE?

Comment: You have to use it in the context of a *test*, I believe with double brackets, so for this specific case piping through (e)grep is much more straightforward.  But it is useful to know about.

Comment: This is specifically a bash comparison operator, which is why it can only be used in tests. Just mentionign this for clarity. Very useful tool.