# bash wildcard n digits

Tags: linux, bash, wildcard

So I've got the following files in the tmp directory:

```
 file.0
 file.1
 file.t9
 file.22
 file.4444
```

if I wanted to list only the files that end in '.digits' (0, 1, 22, 4444) but not (t9) I could try and use wildcards such as this:

```
 ls tmp/file.{[0-9],[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}
```

however I get the following results with the ugly error

```
 ls: cannot access tmp/file.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]: No such file or directory
 file.0
 file.1
 file.22
 file.4444
```

I've also tried using {0..999} but that also results in the same sorts of errors (and a lot more of them). 
Any clues as how to do this without errors from the experts?

Comment: Check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345936/regular-expression-usage-with-ls

Comment: Brace expansion is different from pattern matching. It generates a list of explicit arguments, rather than a pattern to match whatever might be present.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

At least in bash 4, when the `extglob` shell option is enabled:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls /tmp/file.+([0-9])
```

The pattern `+([0-9])` there matches one or more digits.

You can read more about this in the **Pattern Matching** section of `man bash`.

**UPDATE**

Actually, as @chepner pointed out, since `extglob` was introduced in version 2.02, this should work in pretty much every `bash` you come across today, unless you pulled your distro out of a rock or something.

Comment: we musn't be running bash 4 because i get "...unexpected token '('"

Comment: Try again after running `shopt -s extglob`!

Comment: That does work - is that available as standard? Or is my sysop sufficiently awesome to include it?

Comment: On my Debian this works by default. Let's assume your sysop is sufficiently awesome ;-)

Comment: `extglob` was introduced in version 2.02.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, good to know! (Added this bit to my answer.)

Comment: extglob appears to be on by default in Ubuntu 18 for the console, *but* it's not on by default for bash scripts that are run.  They need is enabled explicitly.  To do this, run "shopt -s extglob" after the she-bang.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ls` just to list *all* the files then filter the output of that through `grep`:

```
ls -1 | grep -E '\.[0-9]+$'
```

as per the following test:

```
pax> printf 'file.0\nfile.1\nfile.t9\nfile.22\nfile.4444\n' | grep -E '\.[0-9]+$'
file.0
file.1
file.22
file.4444
```

The `-E` gives you extended regular expressions so that the `+` modifier works. If that's not available to you, you can use the `\.[0-9][0-9]*$` regex instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant for filtering files of a specific extension is to use the `find` command with a set of predicates:

```
find tmp/ -type f -iregex '^.*\.[0-9]+$'
```

The `-type` predicate matches only files and the `-iregex` matches names that end with one or more digits - ignoring case of the name. If you want to filter files that begin with `file` you would use the following instead:

```
find tmp/ -type f -iregex '^.*/file\.[0-9]+$'
```

And finally, if you don't want the whole path displayed for each resulting file, use the following:

```
find tmp/ -type f -iregex '^.*/file\.[0-9]+$' -printf "%f\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution to just prevent seeing (ie hide) "ugly errors" is to redirect standard error to `/dev/null` by appending `2> /dev/null`.  In your example:

```
ls tmp/file.{[0-9],[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]} 2> /dev/null
```

This would give you the results you want and hide any errors.  Works with any linux command or executable that sends output to stdout and errors to stderr.  Note that this does not affect the command return status (`$?`), it just suppresses errors.