# list files with regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, ls

How can do I list all files using ls that have atleast 2 digits in their name? I tried this but it gave me error

```
ls *.log.[1-9][1-9]*.*
ls: *.log.[1-9][1-9]*.*: No such file or directory
```

I tried this and it list all files that have 0 as the second digit.

```
ls *.log.[1-9][0-9]*.*
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345936/regular-expression-usage-with-ls

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use `find` command that supports `-regex` option:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iregex '.*\.log\.[1-9][0-9].*'
```

`-iregex` is used for ignore case comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls | egrep '*.log.[1-9][0-9]*.*'
```