# Exclude filename containing certain string, regexp

Tags: regex, bash

Already saw some negative lookback answers here, for some reason i was not able to use ls -l with these.

Let's assume i have three files:

```
sample_one.zip
sample_two.zip
sample_three.zip
```

What i want is to simply ls -l (regex).zip and exclude filenames containing one and two.
 tried

```
   ls -l '*(?!one|two).zip'
```

but no luck!

Comment: It seems you can use shell globbing with `ls`, but not a regex. As for the lookarounds, you might try `grep` with `-P`: `ls | grep -P '(?<!one|two)\.zip$'` (if you have a GNU `grep`, it will work).

Comment: i actually need it for "cp", and i don't have a grep option :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ls doesn't recognise shell globbing, it just expands before ls see's it. It takes literal strings only.

Comment: @123 Perhaps, I misinterpreted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15346038/3832970).

Comment: `shopt -s extglob;ls *_!(one|two).txt` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can utilize the find command, you could:

```
find -name "*.zip" . ! -regex ".*\(\one\|\two\).zip"
```

You could then use -exec to action the copy.

Comment: You might want to add `-name '*.zip'` to make it more like what's being asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Try rsync if that's a option

```
rsync -av --exclude '*one.zip' --exclude '*two.zip' /from /to
```