# Listing get files with or without date

Tags: unix, ksh, ls

I have files like `file123.txt`, `file.txt`

but when I run `ls -l file[0-9]*.txt`, I'm only getting `file123.txt`.

How do I get both files? I thought `*` means "0 or more", but it's not working. (I'm using ksh, if relevant).

Comment: `ls -l | egrep 'file[0-9]*.txt'` See: [Regular Expression usage with ls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15346038/2374329)

Answer (score 3):

It is Pattern matching, not a regular expression.

`[0-9]` and `*` are distinct patterns. `*` is not a modifier as in a regular expression.

```
* Matches any string, including the null string.
[...]  Matches  any  one  of the enclosed characters.
```

You may use a pattern-list where the `*` is a prefix to the enclosed pattern-list

```
*(pattern-list) Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns.
```

`ls file*([0-9]).txt` would be the syntax for zero or more digits.

```
$ ls file*.txt
file123.txt  filea.txt  file.txt
$ ls file*([0-9]).txt
file123.txt  file.txt
```

For details see 'File Name Generation' in `man ksh`.
Some more examples can be found here [KSH93 Extended Patterns](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2009/01/ksh93-regular-expressions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a number filter, just remove this to return files that start with 'file' and end with '.txt':

```
ls -l file*.txt
```

Comment: ls -l file[0-9]*.txt   - what about this one ? Does it expect atleast one number after file ?   I checked two tutorials and they say [0-9]*  expects zero or more. So in that case my command should work ?

Comment: Yes, [0-9] will expect at least one number. Possibly the tutorials were referring to the number zero? You can test both commands quickly to see.

Comment: @Adriana Possibly the tutorials described `Regular Expressions`? The set of symbols is similar but the meaning is different from Bash `Pattern Matching` for filenames.