# terminal commands to get hidden files ending with a particular pattern

Tags: terminal

I can easily search for non-hidden files in terminal ending with a particular pattern.

```
*for example*
```

Consider these files are present  in the folder in which I am searching

```
      1new   2new   3new   4new  .5new
```

If I enter the command la *ew I get these files as output

```
      1new   2new   3new   4new
```

I am getting the same result when using ls -a *ew

So what command  should I enter in order to get hidden files ending with a particular pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls` does not support regular expressions as per my understanding. So, you might need to pipe the output to some other command like `grep` which supports regular expressions. Try below command and see if it works as per your need.

`ls -a | grep new`

Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345936/regular-expression-usage-with-ls) for more information.